# Updating dynamically added Material Design elements with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

I am using Angular and Material Design Lite in my project, but I have a really annoying problem with dynamically added MDL-elements in Firefox. 
I tried to fix these elements by updating all registered elements like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    $scope.$$postDigest(function() {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();   
    });
});
```

And template:

```
<div ng-repeat="(stockname, stock) in fileData.stocks" class="file_info__stock js_stock {[{ stock.editMode ? 'editable' : '' }]} {[{ stock.detailsView ? 'active' : '' }]}">
    <div class="stock__info">
        <button id="file_info__options_{[{stock.stock_id}]}" class="file_info__options mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
            <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
        </button>
        <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--bottom" data-mdl-for="file_info__options_{[{stock.stock_id}]}">Functions</div>
        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="file_info__options_{[{stock.stock_id}]}">
            <li class="mdl-menu__item js_media__edit" ng-click="editFile(stock);">Edit</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Elements in fileData.stocks are received by POST-request.
Menu and tooltip work nice in Chrome, but in Firefox, I suppose,  componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered(); doesn't work at all.

Does anybody have this problem?